# iOS Keyboard extension disable for other application on iPhone

Tags: ios, swift, custom-keyboard, ios-keyboard-extension

I have developed the custom keyboard in the iOS with the help of Keyboard extension provided by the Xcode. This keyboard installed on the iPhone with containing sample app and it's get added as iOS level. This keyboard is available to use across all the application in the iPhone.

Can i restrict the use of custom keyboard to my application only? I don't want keyboard to be expose to other applications in iPhone.

Comment: No, a keyboard extension is made available to all apps on the device.  If you only want it in your app then you shouldn't create an extension; just implement the keyboard code in your app

Comment: Theres a lot of working around you need to do. Like @Paulw11 said you shouldn't create an extension. Have your keyboard as a custom view in your application, don't allow the native keyboard to display, and you would have to manually handle the key presses in your app.